# how do you add an active class to a particular div

Tags: vuejs2, tailwind-css

```
<newsfeed-view inline-template :newsfeed="{{  $feed }}">
    <article class="bg-white p-8 w-1/2 mt-4 p-4" id="newsfeedPost" v-bind:class="{ 'active' : isHighlighted } ">
        <h3>
            <a href="#" class="text-blue-dark hover:no-underline hover:text-black active:no-underline active:text-4xl" @click="this.isHighlighted = true">{{  $feed->newsfeed_title }}</a>
        </h3>
        <p class="mt-4">{{ $feed->body }}</p>
    </article>
</newsfeed-view>
```

This is my style section

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.highlighted { 
    @apply .border-l-4 .border-orange ;
}

#newsfeedPost { 
    @apply .rounded-lg ; 
}


</style>
```

I want to add the highlighted class if I click on that anchor tag..

Answer (score 0):

Your line `v-bind:class="{ 'active' : isHighlighted }"` will toggle the `active` class. If you want to toggle the `highlighted` class as dictated in your stylesheet, use:

```
v-bind:class="{ 'highlighted' : isHighlighted }"
```